# Tuning Multi-Level Rows-to-Cols Query

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle10g, performance

In the answer to a previous post ([Tuning Rows-to-Cols Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1430186/tuning-rows-to-cols-query/1430323#1430323)), I learned how to more efficiently construct a row-to-cols query which allows for filtering by date.  However, I now need to take this one level further.

The schema for the query below is as follows:
`SAMPLE (1-to-many) TEST (1-to-many) RESULT (1-to-MANY)`
Each sample has one or more tests, and each test has one or more results.

**Question:** How can I rewrite this view more efficiently, still allowing fast filtering by "Date Sampled?"

**Concern:** The points for `MAX(tst.created_on)` should be the set of unique tests with `test_id` (set 1) not for the set of unique results with `test_id` (set 2):

```
set 1: {1,    2,    76,     77,     135,      136}
set 2: {1, 1, 2, 2, 76, 76, 77, 77, 135, 135, 136, 136}
```

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW V_TITRATION_SAMPLES as
     SELECT sam.sampled_on "Date Sampled",
            MAX(CASE WHEN res.result_tmpl_id = 4 THEN result END) "titrator", 
            MAX(CASE WHEN res.result_tmpl_id = 3 THEN result END) "factor",
            MAX(tst.created_on) "Last Test Creation"
       FROM lims.sample sam
       JOIN lims.test tst ON sam.sample_id = tst.sample_id
       JOIN lims.result res ON tst.test_id = res.test_id
      WHERE sam.sample_tmpl_id = 4
   GROUP BY sample_id, sam.sampled_on
```

Before GROUP BY:

```
   SAMPLE COLUMNS      |    TEST COLUMNS     | RESULT COLUMNS
   id  tmp sampled_on  | *id tmp created_on  | *id tmp result
    1   4  09-20 21:50 |   1  7  09-20 22:20 |   1  1     5
    1   4  09-20 21:50 |   1  7  09-20 22:20 |   2  3    2.1
    1   4  09-20 21:50 |   2  9  09-20 22:23 |   3  4     6
    1   4  09-20 21:50 |   2  9  09-20 22:23 |   4  6    123

   25   4  09-21 08:26 |  76  7  09-21 08:53 |  96  1     4
   25   4  09-21 08:26 |  76  7  09-21 08:53 |  97  3    1.6
   25   4  09-21 08:26 |  77  9  09-21 08:52 |  98  4     4
   25   4  09-21 08:26 |  77  9  09-21 08:52 |  99  6    103

  102   4  09-21 09:54 | 135  7  09-21 10:34 | 185  1     1
  102   4  09-21 09:54 | 135  7  09-21 10:34 | 186  3    1.8
  102   4  09-21 09:54 | 136  9  09-21 10:05 | 187  4     5
  102   4  09-21 09:54 | 136  9  09-21 10:05 | 188  6    110

* Shortened TABLE_id and TABLE_template_id to id and tmp, 
  respectively to keep this data grid narrow.
```

Results:

```
   "Date Sampled"  titrator   factor   "Last Test Creation"
   09-20 21:50        6         2.1    09-20 22:23
   09-21 08:26        4         1.6    09-21 08:53
   09-21 09:54        5         1.8    09-21 10:34
```

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand what "only needs to be checked across the tests of the sample not across all results of all tests under the sample" means in this context.  Can you potentially show a sample of the data and show us your expected output?  My wager at this point is that the solution will involve analytic functions but I'm not sure what output you are looking for, so I'm not sure which function to suggest.

Comment: The schema description is not clear. And can you (1) use aliases for all tables and (2) replace "using" clauses with "on"?

Comment: I simplified the main question.  It should be clearer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a shot:

```
WITH titrate AS (
     SELECT r.test_id,
            MAX(r.result) 'titrator'
       FROM LIMS.RESULT r
      WHERE r.result_tmpl_id = 4
   GROUP BY r.test_id),
    factor AS (
     SELECT r.test_id,
            MAX(r.result) 'factor'
       FROM LIMS.RESULT r
      WHERE r.result_tmpl_id = 3
   GROUP BY r.test_id),
     created AS (
     SELECT t.sample_id,
            MAX(t.created_on) 'created'
       FROM LIMS.TEST t
   GROUP BY t.sample_id)
   SELECT s.sampled_on,
          ti.titrator,
          f.factor,
          t.created
     FROM LIMS.SAMPLE s
     JOIN created t ON t.sample_id = s.sample_id
LEFT JOIN titrate ti ON ti.test_id = t.test_id
LEFT JOIN factor f ON f.test_id = t.test_id
```

I changed out the CASE statements using subquery factoring - the LEFT JOIN may not be necessary.

The key part is the inline view/subquery factoring for the LIMS.TEST table, where you want to get the max `created_on` date for a `sample_id` - separating it from the rest of the query will give you more control to return what you want specifically from that table.

The equivalent alternative using inline views - they'll perform the same, just that subquery factoring is only supported since 9i:

```
   SELECT s.sampled_on,
          ti.titrator,
          f.factor,
          t.created
     FROM LIMS.SAMPLE s
     JOIN (SELECT t.sample_id,
                  MAX(t.created_on) 'created'
             FROM LIMS.TEST t
         GROUP BY t.sample_id) t ON t.sample_id = s.sample_id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT r.test_id,
                  MAX(r.result) 'titrator'
             FROM LIMS.RESULT r
            WHERE r.result_tmpl_id = 4
         GROUP BY r.test_id) ti ON ti.test_id = t.test_id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT r.test_id,
                  MAX(r.result) 'factor'
             FROM LIMS.RESULT r
            WHERE r.result_tmpl_id = 3
         GROUP BY r.test_id) f ON f.test_id = t.test_id
```